How do I switch a numeric value in a column in a pandas dataframe with the value in another column?
Posting a solution to a problem that I didn't see on Stack Overflow. I have two columns in a pandas datframe. One has numeric values that need to be switched with the values in another column.
Creating a dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame([['Captain', 'Crunch', 72],
               ['Trix', 36, 'Rabbit'],
               ['Count', 'Chocula', 41],
               ['Tony', 54, 'Tiger'],
               ['Buzz', 28, 'Bee'],
               ['Toucan', 'Sam', 38]],
              columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])

Dataframe input:
  first_name    last_name       age
0   Captain        Crunch        72
1   Trix               36    Rabbit
2   Count         Chocula        41
3   Tony               54     Tiger
4   Buzz               28       Bee
5   Toucan            Sam        38

Desired output:
 first_name     last_name       age
0   Captain        Crunch        72
1   Trix           Rabbit        36
2   Count          Chocula       41
3   Tony            Tiger        54
4   Buzz              Bee        28
5   Toucan            Sam        38


One option is to use np.sort()
cols = ['last_name','age']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols].astype(str).to_numpy(),axis=1)[:,::-1]

Output:
  first_name last_name age
0    Captain    Crunch  72
1       Trix    Rabbit  36
2      Count   Chocula  41
3       Tony     Tiger  54
4       Buzz       Bee  28
5     Toucan       Sam  38


I had this idea in mind, but this won't work if you have numbers in the strings (e.g. 0Crunch)

yes good point, this solution would only work if the dataset was guaranteed to have clean last names

You can use to_numeric to identify the numbers and form a mask, then swap the columns with boolean indexing:
m = pd.to_numeric(df['age'], errors='coerce').isna()
df.loc[m, ['age', 'last_name']] = df.loc[m, ['last_name', 'age']].values

Then optionally convert "age" to int dtype:
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(int)

Output:
  first_name last_name age
0    Captain    Crunch  72
1       Trix    Rabbit  36
2      Count   Chocula  41
3       Tony     Tiger  54
4       Buzz       Bee  28
5     Toucan       Sam  38

If you can have NaNs in "age" then use the alternative mask:
m = pd.to_numeric(df['last_name'], errors='coerce').notna()


Here is the solution that worked for me:
import numpy as np

def is_numeric(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

df['last_name'],df['age'] = np.where(df['last_name'].apply(is_numeric),(df['age'], df['last_name']), (df['last_name'], df['age']))


What is is_numeric in your code?

@mozway- whoops, thanks for point this out. Revised to include is_numeric.

Here is a solution that I used:
first check which rows are not int in age. then swap using the index.
mask = df['age'].apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, int))
df.loc[mask, ['last_name', 'age']] = df.loc[mask, ['age', 'last_name']].values

